# when importing multiple javascript files the javascript seems to break

Tags: javascript, jquery, import

I am trying to incorperate several different js files into one page. For some reason though whichever ones are first, seem to break. Here is the code I am using:

```
<link href="inc/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="inc/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inc/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inc/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/js/jquery.slideshow.lite-0.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#slideshow2").slideshow({
                pauseSeconds: 6,
                height: 196
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The first files are used for a lightbox and other functions and the second ones are used for a slideshow. Depending on the order one or the other will work, but never both at the same time. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: JQuery has many lightbox implementation. have you thought about scraping the proto lightbox and porting to a jquery based one?

Answer (score 3):

You need to run jquery in no-conflict mode, see:

- http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries
- http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict

From the above:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="prototype.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script>
     jQuery.noConflict();

     // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("div").hide();
     });

     // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
     $('someid').hide();
   </script>
 </head>
 <body></body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. I'm not completely sure of the syntax though, do I have to add all of the code you supplied from 
"jQuery.noConflict();

     // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("div").hide();
     });

     // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
     $('someid').hide();"

If so where abouts? Is it possible you can paste the code I'm missing into what I posted?

Thanks so much.

Comment: @waywardmd - No, you don't, that's just an example of how it is used. Include prototype before jquery, and just put the line jQuery.noConflict(); at the beginning of your script. I would suggest reading the links I have provided.

Comment: @waywardmd - Also, when writing jQuery script, make sure to use jQuery instead of the '$' that prototype uses, e.g. jQuery.hide("slow");

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery and prototype, which both define a `$()` function.

You need to use

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```